# How to Solve this Conditional Probability Problem? Probability of Twins

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability, genetics

I'm working on a problem from a textbook (self-study) ([Casella and Berger](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0534243126)).

**The Problem**

Given these facts/assumptions...

- ⅓ of human twins are identical (one-egg) and ⅔ are fraternal (two-egg).
- identical twins are the same sex with sexes being equally likely.
- among fraternal twins, ¼ are female, ¼ are male, and ½ are male/female.
- among all US births, 1/90 are twins.

Let:

$$
\begin{align}
A\ &=\ \{Births\ which\ Result\ in\ Twin\ Females\} \\
B\ &=\ \{Births\ which\ Result\ in\ Identical\ Twins\} \\
C\ &=\ \{Births\ which\ Result\ in\ Twins\} 
\end{align}
$$

and find P($A \cap B \cap C$), i.e. the probability of identical twin females.

**My attempt to solve**

The first thing I tried to do was translate the above facts into probability statements that can be used to calculate P($A \cap B \cap C$).

- ⅓ of human twins are identical (one-egg) and ⅔ are fraternal (two-egg).

Given a set of twins, a fraction of them are either identical or fraternal:

$$
\begin{align}
P(identical\ |\ twins) &= \frac{1}{3} \\
P(fraternal\ |\ twins) &= \frac{2}{3} \\
\end{align}
$$

- identical twins are the same sex with sexes being equally likely.

$$
\begin{align}
P(female\ |\ identical\ twins)\ = P(male\ |\ identical\ twins) = \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}
$$

- among fraternal twins, ¼ are female, ¼ are male, and ½ are male/female.

$$
\begin{align}
P(female\ |\ fraternal\ twins) = P(male\ |\ fraternal\ twins) &= \frac{1}{4} \\
P(male/female\ |\ fraternal\ twins) &= \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}
$$

- among all US births, 1/90 are twins.

$$
P(twins) = \frac{1}{90}
$$

Stuck on this one... do $A$, $B$ and $C$ have to be calculated individually in order to calculate P($A \cap B \cap C$)?

Comment: Your notation is vague: could you explain what a set of "birth results" might refer to in your definitions of $A,B,C$?  Are you just trying to compute the proportion of US births that are identical twin girls?

Comment: @whuber I updated the terms for the definitions of $A$, $B$ and $C$. Yes, I believe the problem is just asking for the probability of births that are identical twin girls.

Comment: This seems like it could be a homework problem, so I don't want to provide a full answer. But as a hint, try factoring the probabilities. Remember that you can express intersections in terms of conditional probabilities. For example, $P(E \cap F) = P(E | F) P(F)$.